# Making sure the logic of my code is sound. This code will eventually lead into a java representation of yahtzee

Tags: java

I'm making a class for the Straight category of Yahtzee. Yahtzee has 2 options for a straight, small or larger. A small straight would be a sequence of 4 consecutive die faces such as 1, 2, 3, 4. A larger straight would be  a sequence of 5 consecutive die faces. If a player get a small straight they receive 30 points and if they get a larger that is 40 points.

My Straight class inherits from a class called Scores and only uses one method called getDiceScore. The getDiceScore will accept an argument of type DieInterface. I will attach the DieInterface interface code below.

I just want to make sure the logic of my code is sound for this project I am working on.

```
public interface DieInterface
{
    public static String[] dieFaces =
        {"+---+\n|   |\n| o |\n|   |\n+---+",
         "+---+\n|o  |\n|   |\n|  o|\n+---+",
         "+---+\n|o  |\n| o |\n|  o|\n+---+",
         "+---+\n|o o|\n|   |\n|o o|\n+---+",
         "+---+\n|o o|\n| o |\n|o o|\n+---+",
         "+---+\n|o o|\n|o o|\n|o o|\n+---+"};

    public static String toDieString(DieInterface aDie)
    {
        return dieFaces[aDie.getFaceValue()-1];
    }

    // Do not modify above this line

    public static String toDiceString(DieInterface[] dice)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String sideBySide = "";
        String die1 = dieFaces[dice[0].getFaceValue()-1];
        String die2 = dieFaces[dice[1].getFaceValue()-1];
        String die3 = dieFaces[dice[2].getFaceValue()-1];
        String die4 = dieFaces[dice[3].getFaceValue()-1];
        String die5 = dieFaces[dice[4].getFaceValue()-1];
        //String die6 = dieFaces[dice[5].getFaceValue()-1];
        String splitter = die1 + "\n" + die2 + "\n" + die3 + "\n"+ die4 + "\n"+ die4+ "\n"+ die5;
        String [] temp = splitter.split("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < (temp.length/6); i++)
        {
            result.append(temp[0*(5)+i] + "  " + temp[1*(5)+i] + "  " + temp[2*(5)+i] +"  " +  temp[3*(5)+i] +"  "+ temp[4*(5)+i] +"\n");
        }

        return result.toString();

    }

    // Do not modify below this line
    public int roll();
    public int getFaceValue();
}

public class Straight extends Scores
{
    protected String name;
    protected int numConsecutiveFaces; // indicates how many consecutive faces that a player should have to satisfy this scoring category 
    public Straight(String aName, int numConsecutiveFaces)
    {
        super(aName);
        this.numConsecutiveFaces = numConsecutiveFaces;
    }
    public int getDiceScore(DieInterface[] dice)
    {
        boolean ones = false;//determines that only one side of a die appeared once
        int[] straight = new int[numConsecutiveFaces]; // array used to store numbers in the correct straight format
        int [] counter = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0}; //using to track how many times a die appeared 
        //looping through dice array to determine how many times a die appeared 
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {
            counter[dice[i].getFaceValue()-1]++;
        }
        //sorting the die in sequential order
        sort(counter);

        //determining that a die only appeared once and they are no larger than by one value. ex 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 not 2, 3, 5, 6
        for(int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++)
        {
            if(counter[i] == 1 && byAFactorOfOne(counter, counter) == true)
            {
                ones = true;
                byAFactorOfOne(counter, counter);
                counter[i] = straight[i];
            }
         }
        //if 4 die in a row are in correct sequential order return 30 points back
        if(straight[numConsecutiveFaces] == 4)
            return 30;
        //if 5 die in a row are in correct sequential order return 40 points back
        else if(straight[numConsecutiveFaces] == 5)
            return 40;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

    private void sort(int[] counter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <counter.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < counter.length - i - 1; j++) 
            {
                if (counter[j] > counter[j + 1]) 
                {
                    int temp = counter[j];
                    counter[j] = counter[j + 1];
                    counter[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean byAFactorOfOne(int[] counter, int[] counter2)
    {
        int value;
        int counting = 0;
        boolean repeat = true;
        int i = 0;

        while(repeat && counting < counter.length)
        {
            value = counter[i] - counter[i + 1];
            i++;
            if(value != 1)
            {
                repeat = false;
                return false;
            }
            counting ++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following code won't work:

```
if(straight[numConsecutiveFaces] == 4)
```

... because you aren't setting any values into the `straight` array.

---

You are counting the number of times each die value is displayed:

```
//looping through dice array to determine how many times a die appeared 
for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
{
    counter[dice[i].getFaceValue()-1]++;
}
```

... and the index of the array is the value on the die. This makes sense.

But as soon as you sort these values, you lose which die value each count represents. **Don't do this**:

```
//sorting the die in sequential order
sort(counter);
```

If you did that, you no longer know which die value was displayed n times.

Instead of sorting `counter`, what you need to do is look for 4 or 5 consecutive entries that are not 0. In other words, 4 or 5 consecutive entries that had at least one die showing that value.

You can take some shortcuts:

1. If `counter[3]` or `counter[4]` is zero, it's not possible for either a 4-length or 5-length straight
2. If `counter[2]` and `counter[5]` are both 0, it's not possible for a 5-length straight
3. If there are any `counter` values > 1, then it's not possible for a 5-length straight to have occurred
4. And if there are more than 1 `counter` values > 1, then it's not possible for a 4-length straight to have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve this problem that doesn't involve counting values or sorting (uses binary values to represent the presence of a die value):

```
public class Straight extends Scores
{

    static final int valueForOneToFour = Math.pow(2, 0) + Math.pow(2, 1) + Math.pow(2, 2) + Math.pow(2, 3);
    static final int valueForTwoToFive = Math.pow(2, 1) + Math.pow(2, 2) + Math.pow(2, 3) + Math.pow(2, 4);
    static final int valueForThreeToSix = Math.pow(2, 2) + Math.pow(2, 3) + Math.pow(2, 4) + Math.pow(2, 5);

    static final int valueForOneToFive = Math.pow(2, 0) + Math.pow(2, 1) + Math.pow(2, 2) + Math.pow(2, 3) + Math.pow(2, 4);
    static final int valueForTwoToSix = Math.pow(2, 1) + Math.pow(2, 2) + Math.pow(2, 3) + Math.pow(2, 4) + Math.pow(2, 5);

    ...

    public int getDiceScore(DieInterface[] dice)
    {
        // calculate a binary representation of the values available
        int occurrenceValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            occurrenceValue |= Math.pow(2, dice[i] - 1));
        }

        if (occurrenceValue & valueForOneToFive == valueForOneToFive
                || occurrenceValue & valueForTwoToSix == valueForTwoToSix) {
            return 40;
        }

        if (occurrenceValue & valueForOneToFour == valueForOneToFour
                || occurrenceValue & valueForTwoToFive == valueForTwoToFive
                || occurrenceValue & valueForThreeToSix == valueForThreeToSix) {
            return 30;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```